# Is there a list of icons and their respective buffs?

Tags: the-division-2

When playing, the UI displays your buffs. I don't recognise all the buff icons as often they are applied by another player. So I can't read the description from my inventory screen.

I have highlighted the area, with a few example icons in the image below.

[image: Division 2 UI with buffs]

Is there a list of which buffs are for which icons so that I can better understand what they are doing and leverage their bonuses more efficiently?